# Create a sql where condition using Alias in Zend

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I'm using zend and I got stuck in creating a where conditon on the alias:

Sample code:

```
$select = $db->select()
             ->from(array('p' => 'products'), 'p.product_id')
             ->columns('product_name', 'p')
             ->where('p = ?', 'value');
             // Alternatively use columns('p.product_name')
```

Revised Code

```
$select = $db->select()
             ->from(array('p' => 'products'), 'p.product_id')
             ->columns(array('x' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(SELECT...)'                    
        )))
             ->where('x = ?', 'value');
             // Alternatively use columns('p.product_name')
```

Im creating a condition for x

This produces error. Can anyone tell me what I missed?

Comment: You can echo $select->assemble() to see the query

Answer (score 1):

Your format seems wrong.

I think in your case it should be like below,

```
$select = $db->select()
         ->from(array('p' => 'products'))
         ->columns('product_name')
         ->where('p.id = ?', 'value');
```

Ref: [Zend Db Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html/)

Comment: i revised my question, please re-read it if you have time... thanks